# Omitting credentials on react native fetch

Tags: react-native

Im trying to stop the react-native implementation of `fetch` to send the cookie to the server as i'd like to supply my own custom logic for it. I would expect that

```
 const response = await fetch(apiURL, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers,
      credentials: "omit",
    });
```

would do the trick but it clearly doesnt work as when i inspect the outbound traffic with Wireshark the Cookie gets sent anyway..

Any clues? I'd rather not have to dive into the fetch implementation code but im starting to entertaing the idea..

Comment: There is a known issue with fetch API not respecting the "credentials: omit" on react native.
A workaround for this is to clear the cookies before sending the request (usually using react-native-cookies npm module). You could create a wrapper function for your requests that saves the cookie you need in AsyncStorage, clears all cookies before every request and set it only each time you need it. 
Read more here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12956

Comment: Oh my god thank you, i was thinking of doing the exact same thing but it felt very hacky, now you gave me the greenlight to go town and write a comment that amends my behaviour.

Thanks so much, this has been eating at me.

Comment: Ran into a very similar situation. My case was even worse since the cookies weren't even being set properly. Facebook mentions this in the issues with using fetch. I chose to fallback and use XMLHttpRequest instead. Fixed all my problems.

Comment: @johnborges after a lot of pain we ended up doing away with the idea of using cookies on react-native, a lot more issues came up. I would highly suggest going with a token based authentication system. I know, the backend people probably will side-eye you but if possible it will save you a lot of pain down the road.

Comment: I good idea, and a much better practice. I unfortunately couldn't do this for a project I was working on.